# Memory Related Crash : 3 Dimensional Array in Cocos2d Game

Tags: c++, c, iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Here is Code:

Declaration in .h

```
@interface LevelManager : NSObject{

}
@property int ***construtorDeMundo;
```

Initialisation and malloc

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil){
        construtorDeMundo = (int***) malloc ( NUMFASES * sizeof(int *));

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMFASES ; i++) {
            construtorDeMundo[i] = (int**) malloc (MAX_PONTOS_CRITICOS * sizeof(int));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMFASES; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX_PONTOS_CRITICOS; j++) {
                construtorDeMundo[i][j] = (int*) malloc (PROPRIEDADES * sizeof(int));
                for (int k = 0; k < PROPRIEDADES ; k++)
                    construtorDeMundo[i][j][k] = 0;
            }

        [self pegaInformacoes];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Code to access:

```
 for (int j = 1; j < [elements count]; j++) {
            if(j <= PROPRIEDADES+1){
                NSString *valor = (NSString *)[elements objectAtIndex:j];
                construtorDeMundo[fase][i][j-1] = [((NSNumber*)valor) intValue];
            }
        }
```

Game randomly crashes for different index in last function. Something related to malloc...How to fix ? Please help me if you know.

Sorry this game code is not in English...not written by me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do I start... 1. Don't EVER allocate arrays manually, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). 2. Don't allocate 3D arrays as `a[i][j][k]`, but create a one-dimensional array with size that fits all three dimensions and use a custom accessor to reach element `(i,j,k)`. This is much faster and cache-friendly.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist yes your suggestions is great and heard while google also...but in this game lots of place this level manager used...so changing it to vector may take many days...so looking for actual problem in above allocation.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, except for what I mentioned before. Use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or some similar memory analysis tool to find out. btw, it might be cheaper to change this to a vector, believe it or not. It's now **your** code. Fixing it may entail more than just fixing two lines. The question is how long it takes, not how many lines you're gonna change.

Comment: Thanks for your great words Sir...will try my best...One strange observation is it works perfect in 32-bit device...problem only in 64-bit..In other words worked perfect in iOS7 now in iOS12 only crashing...will research something more...thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Fixed problem. In above code, wrong value provided for sizeof().

Here is updated code:

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil){
        construtorDeMundo = (int***) malloc ( (NUMFASES) * sizeof(*construtorDeMundo));

        for (int i=0; i < NUMFASES; ++i)
            construtorDeMundo[i] = NULL;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMFASES ; ++i) {
            construtorDeMundo[i] = (int**) malloc (MAX_PONTOS_CRITICOS * sizeof(*construtorDeMundo[i]));
        }

        for (int i=0; i < NUMFASES; ++i)
            for (int j=0; j < MAX_PONTOS_CRITICOS; ++j)
                construtorDeMundo[i][j] = NULL;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMFASES; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX_PONTOS_CRITICOS; ++j) {
                construtorDeMundo[i][j] = (int*) malloc ((PROPRIEDADES) * sizeof(*construtorDeMundo[i][j]));
                for (int k = 0; k < PROPRIEDADES ; k++)
                    construtorDeMundo[i][j][k] = 0;
            }


        [self pegaInformacoes];
    }
    return self;
}
```